# Infragistics grid not working properly in ei-11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, grid, infragistics

We are using Infragistics grid on our site, and people that have upgraded to ei-11, have problems, where the sorting doesn't work anymore. When clicked on a them, instead of sorting, it does grouping.
Have anyone experienced this or similar problems? I do not have access to the code from this computer, but if needed, I'll paste some later

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in case some other people have the same problem.
In the displayLayout out, I changed the viewtype from outlookGroupBy to flat. So in code

```
<DisplayLayout ViewType="Flat" ... />
```

Before the above, I had

```
<DisplayLayout ViewType="outlookGroupBy" ... />
```

which caused the error of auto grouping when someone wanted to sort

Comment: This will prevent grouping because grouping is disabled in the grid.  If someone wants to have grouping and sorting, then this solution will not work.  Is the issue present if your users use compatibility view?